# Can the upvote and downvote counts be shown separately?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, down-votes, up-votes, vote-count

Sometimes I felt just total vote count do not represent the whole scenario(liking/disliking) of the community. In case of mine, my [last question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68214/can-stack-exchange-follow-a-more-generic-approach) got upvoted 5 times and downvoted 4 times. But the total vote, 1 does not represent so many difference of opinions in the community. So, can the upvote and downvote counts be shown separately? The sorting still will be on the total votes. But the numbers will show more information.

Comment: This is already available to users with at least 1000 rep: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-vote-counts

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You *can* view the total vote counts [once you have 1000 rep points](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation), by clicking on the number. Here's what it looks like (after clicking):

[image]

IIRC, the justification for not showing it to everyone right away was twofold: 1) it would put too much additional stress on the servers, and 2) we wanted to have something to give users who pass that nice threshold; before that, there was a rather large gap between 500 (retagging) and 1500 (creating new tags) rep points.

Comment: Showing two numbers instead of one number puts stress on the servers!?

Comment: Thanks for the shot of my question. But I sill think the first point is quite lame.

Comment: @Peter: quoting Jeff: ["The total vote count (score) is denormalized, but the individual up/down vote counts are not. So to display it on every post would incur 2 vote table queries * number of visible questions / answers. Our DB is fast, but the vote table is pretty massive, and not doing a query is always faster than doing it. It's possibly something we could do on demand, but as an 'always displayed' it is a non-starter."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/)

Comment: You didn't need to quote all that - the first sentence is the problem: "The total vote count (score) is denormalized, but the individual up/down vote counts are not." - why not?

Comment: (looks like Cletus asked the same question on the other answer, and got ignored. hmph)

Answer (score 15):

If you're inclined to do some math, then regardless of reputation you can actually determine the current upvote and downvote count of posts in a question using the improved Timeline view! You can access it on any question by entering the URL of

```
<site>/posts/<questionid>/timeline
```

This shows a spread of all activity in that question, including days that votes were cast on any posts in the question. So if you're up to tallying it up, you can use it to determine how many upvotes and downvotes that individual posts have prior to reaching 1k.

It's naturally much easier to do it using the 1k tool as well as stressful for very old questions that have a lot of activity, but if you *really* need to know and can't wait to earn that reputation, remember that the Timeline is always available.

Comment: +1, interesting. I must have missed the introduction of this feature.

Comment: There's now an easier way to access the timeline without entering the link manually, i.e., by clicking on the clock icon next to every post (questions *and* answers).

Answer (score 2):

When you get above a certain rep (1000), you can click the number to view this information.

It would be nice though if there was the option to show both values without clicking when there are both up and down votes.