# See how many downvotes and upvotes a question got

Tags: support, voting, down-votes

In the comments on a question of mine on SO, a couple people mentioned they did not like the downvotes I was receiving. How can they tell I got a downvote, other than comparing the vote rating over time? Is there a button somewhere I can't find or is it just because it is my question? Perhaps I cannot see some information because the question is now closed?

The question: [John the Ripper Custom Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737606/john-the-ripper-custom-rule)

Comment: Click on the vote number between the arrows.  That will split the vote tally into two numbers; upvotes and downvotes.  I think you might need a minimum amount of reputation already to be able to do this.

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68289/can-the-upvote-and-downvote-counts-be-shown-separately

Comment: This question was asked a gazillion times before. Oddly enough, the vote count is very diverse in each situation!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a certain reputation (1000), you can.

[Established user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user)

Answer (score 6):

At 1000 (100 in private beta and 750 in public beta) rep, you can access this information. Click on the current vote tally and it will change to show the number of upvotes and downvotes. As of the time of this answer, you (OP) need a just a tad more rep.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have 1000 reputation, there are other options:

- You can check the [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294435/jamesbtate?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2011-01-19%2000:00:00Z&page=3) of the author's profile. (This doesn't work on per-site metas, though.)

  [image: reputation tab]
- You can get the number of up- and downvotes from the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com), e.g. from [the /posts/{ids} method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=4737606&filter=!-*jbN*u6j6OL&site=stackoverflow&run=true):

  [image: API response]
- It's possible to fetch the number of downvotes via a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1069887/number-of-up-and-downvotes-for-a-single-post?postID=4737606), though it's only refreshed once a week, on Sunday morning, so it's not useful for recent votes.

  [image]

Comment: I downloaded [this little script](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) years ago, still works, and I use it across the network. I've not downloaded it on my mobile though. I'm not sure if it works and whether it's worth the trouble.