# Why are the number of up/down votes secret in meta?

Tags: feature-request, voting, meta

Frequently when I'm facing a situation in stackoverflow where I'm not sure what the expected behavior/etiquette is I go to meta to look it up.

A lot of times when I'm looking through meta questions I see questions with `+1` reputation or `0` reputation. In stackoverflow I can click that number (having more than 1000 reputation) and gain a much better understanding of how the community feels about that answer/question.

I understand that since stackoverflow has a lot of traffic [showing downvotes and upvotes is expensive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/1007#1007) for all users in stackoverflow.

However in meta I feel that knowing the ratio between downvotes and upvotes in meta is crucial to differentiating something that did not get enough attention from a highly debated subject (or people don't have a strong opinion on, and something people do). If I see a question with `0` often I can not tell if the community does not care or it is highly debated.

**In short:**

I would like to know *why* meta enforces the 1000 reputation limit for showing up/down votes?

What are some advantages and disadvantages to it in the context of *meta*?

Comment: +1 I personally think, that Meta should get rid of reputation and provide full feature support from the start for experienced SO users (e.g. having 1000).

Comment: *"If I see a question with 0 often I can not tell if the community does not care or it is highly debated."*...wouldn't the presence or absence of debate be a give-away?

Comment: @Bart: Maybe, but I agree with the OP that you shouldn't have to read-between-the-lines in such a way to determine that.

Comment: @Mat: Meh, [meta-tag:discussion] vs [meta-tag:feature-request]? :P

Comment: @Bart you're right that's a good point, sometimes it does help but not always. Especially for a user like me that mostly comments/answers on stackoverflow and _reads_ meta it's hard to pick up on the nuances of meta.

Comment: I would love to see both Up and Down vote totals without clicking on meta, just because of the way Downvotes can mean Disagreement on meta, and not necessarily Bad Answer. It gives a more accurate view about what the community thinks of the question/answer. And I know there's times when the top voted answer is not actually the question at the top, just because it has more downvotes too.

Comment: Personally I think that SE should denormalize both vote counts, at which point the performance argument becomes moot. Denormalizing two small integers can't be much more expensive than denormalizing one.

Comment: @Codes huh? Not sure what you mean. This is not a normalization issue. The counts are visible but only to 1k+ rep users.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Codes was reffering to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69852/why-is-it-a-privilege-to-view-vote-counts) I think.

Comment: @dystroy ahh, I see.

Comment: Another related feature-request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82442/view-vote-count-privilege-should-be-much-easier-to-gain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a UserScript you can use to view the vote totals without having 1000 reputation points available on stackapps:

["View Vote totals" without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep)

Quoted from stackapps:

> The vote counts are a great tool to determine whether an answer is disputed or not. Unfortunately, not many of us have enough time to join all Stack Exchange websites and get 1000 reputation.
>
> This script unlocks the "View Vote counts" feature for those who are not logged in or don't have 1k reputation. The look and feeling of the feature is identical to the original one.
>
> Recognises posts at question and /review/ pages.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but it's damn useful so I give a +1 to your comment.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I didn't know that. The fact that it is available with a userscript indicates it is not hard to implement which is even more peculiar.