# Is it necessary to have to climb up the rights ladder when many privileges have already been given to you in another SE Site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

I am a member of several SE sites, mainly the programming and english sites. I have already accumulated enough rep to have basic privilege to post comments to questions and answers, vote, answer my own question, etc...

**Is it necessary to have to climb up the rights ladder when many privileges have already been given to you in another SE Site?**

For example, yesterday I asked a question on the Music.SE, then inadvertently found the answer to my question soon after. It happens. But I was unable to provide an answer to my question immediately, having to wait because I didn't have enough rep. Now at this moment in time the Music.SE site isn't a site I can add much expertise to, or have many questions for but sometimes I come across a question where I can add an extra two cents to help out but really should be comments rather than answers. Other times I find that I have a comment of value to add, but since I don't have the rep I don't bother and thus perhaps users lose potential helpful comments.

I wonder if it is necessary to have to climb up the ladder of the basic rights every time one joins a new SE site if you already have a bit of rep in other SE sites?

**The question has been answered, get 200 rep in a SE site and the doors will open. Thank you.**

Comment: Once you receive over 200 reputation, you get a 100-point reputation bonus on all SE sites. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5983/should-all-linked-accounts-get-the-100-bonus)

Comment: Ahhh, so it does exist ^_^ Ok, so Now I know what to work towards.

Comment: See also - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90655/unlock-10k-tools-for-a-user-once-they-have-earned-15k-across-the-se-network-on

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Because people don't agree with the suggestion. Down-votes work differently on meta.

Comment: Probably a combination of people disagreeing with this idea and people being annoyed at seeing it being proposed again, @Mallow.

Comment: Ok good, I was worried there... Although, I don't understand what they don't agree with since jwiscarson and Scrooge just confirmed it existed. Perhaps my wording doesn't reflect that.

Comment: @Mallow They're probably not bothering to read and assuming you're asking for all abilities to transfer between sites, which has been suggested many times in the past

Comment: possible duplicate of [Consider: Users with 50 reputation in any of the SO sites should be able to comment everyone in all of the SO sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101345/consider-users-with-50-reputation-in-any-of-the-so-sites-should-be-able-to-comm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different sites, different communities. So even if you earned good rep on websites related to programming (for example, [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and [gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)) that doesn't mean that the community is the same.

If you were to go onto a website that was completely different, like math.SE and music.SE, then it would be best if you had to earn the privileges on these different websites.

But your problem about the "answer my own question"; I do agree with you to an extent in this area, certain privileges don't really have anything to do with the contents of the website, unlike upvoting/downvoting and editting. It would be nice if the SE accounts would have standards amongst all of them that if you earned specific rights in a group of related SE accounts, those rights would be retained if you used a different SE of a similar category, like gamedev and stackoverflow.

Comment: I understand the community part, and you understand the basic limited feature part I am trying to refer to, hehe :) So this is good.

Comment: One of the things reputation measures is **domain** knowledge. So it's only right that you have to earn the privileges that come with that. The 100 point rep bonus (assuming you have at least 200 on one site) **is** to get you over the hurdle of voting, commenting etc. The solution is to get 200 on one site.

Comment: @Scrooge Today, I just got 200 rep on meta, but that was no increase in stackoverflow. 1. Are meta accounts different? 2.Does it take the system some time to award you the 100 rep?

Comment: @Gabe - This site is different from other metas in that it's reputation is real. If you haven't got the bonus by tomorrow contact the team. The association script probably only runs once a day.

Comment: @Scrooge So do you get 100 points for every 200 points you make, or is it just the first 200 points only?

Comment: Just the first 200 points.