# A place to ask everything on earth?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Stack Exchange follow a more generic approach?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68214/can-stack-exchange-follow-a-more-generic-approach)

I am a programmer developing apps for iPhone, just want to ask a question on how to write a good press release for one of my iPhone applications. I started on stackoverflow, it was closed by some guys, one of the guys told me to go to ask on programmers.stackexchange.com, there I got a warm welcome by a downvote to my question as it's off topic, and directed again to answers.onstartups.com. I don't know if I have enough luck for my question to be answered on the new site.

My question is: WHY NOT CREATE A SITE FOR ASKING EVERYTHING ON EARTH??? I can even ask about developing my apps, or even how to cook a good meal, or even where to travel.

An example: I am going to travel to the U.S, just want to know some suggestions for buying an iPad in NYC. Where is the proper place for this? Do I have to search for all stackexchange sites for the right place to ask?

Comment: Yahoo Answers? ;)

Comment: The problem with your questions is that they're both quite subjective. There are lots of places online to ask subjective questions. Stack Exchange sites are going after the "objective, questions-that-can-be-definitively-answered niche." So, there really is no SE site for what you want. Doesn't mean your questions are bad, but they're not what SE is looking for. Also, this proposal has been made dozens of times before; I linked to one below that seemed very close to what you want.

Comment: I totally disagree with Simon, we are here because we love the way StackOverflow work, we are here because we find something good from the sites. I used to use Yahoo Answers and other sites, but they just don't work the way I like. Your comment is equal to: Why stackoverflow.com and not any vBulletin site?

Comment: @Popular Demand, thanks for the link

Comment: `A place to ask everything on earth?` We need a new SE site: `42`!

Comment: Also Yahoo Answers has a horrible interface.  Answers get selected as "accepted" just for being the first to answer.  This does not help anyone find the right answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you create a site for all subjects, nobody is going to find the answer.

The power of SO is the concentration of people with the right knowledge. And even the programming field is too broad for some hence the number of similar proposals on SE.

Besides, you can use google and wikipedia if you want broad knowledge on (almost) any subject.

Comment: I disagree, by using tags you can solve the problems. wiki is an example, there's everything there, but it's not powered by an ask-answer mechanism. If there's a need to concentrate, then I would suggest to divide into multiple languages for asking everything. Dividing into multiple communities for me is a real failure. No one except existing stackoverflow programmers would know about the existence of the cooking communities (just from my point of view)

Comment: @Hoang, sounds like you'd be interested in this proposal: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68214/can-stack-exchange-follow-a-more-generic-approach

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [health meters for Area51 sites](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq), a healthy site has a good concentration of users who know the subject who can provide excellent, well though out answers (the experts)...and thus the site is a great resource worth its place where peoples questions are answered...ultimately making the internet a better place.

A stack exchange question site about everything is simply going to fail in pretty much every way (feel free to quote me one day if I'm wrong)...

Answer (score 2):

...because there are many sites like that already?

- Yahoo Answers: http://answers.yahoo.com
- WikiAnswers: http://wiki.answers.com
- Askville: http://askville.amazon.com
- Yeda: http://aolanswers.com

Why create yet another one?

Comment: because no other one works the way stackoverflow work

Comment: @Hoang: but... you're *complaining* about the way stackoverflow works...

Comment: I'm not complaining about stackoverflow, but complaining about having too many community stackexchange sites with small number of users, you need to think thousand times which family sites to ask, it's a disaster.

Comment: @hoang yes, thinking is hard, and thinking about where to ask your question and *how* to ask your question is hard -- that's all as it should be. Questions are easy, everyone has a million questions. Answers on the other hand, are not so easy to come by.

Comment: I'd say creating yet another "answer to every question possible" site is not a good solution to a problem of "too many 'answer every question possible' sites".

Comment: ...but I wouldn't be opposed to a place where you could ask "What's the best place to ask this question?" and maybe even "What should I do to make this question better, easier to understand?"