# Is there a way to set up a cross-site feed of Stack Exchange questions?

Tags: feature-request, feed, site-crossover

I'm a member of several Stack Exchange sites, and it would be lovely if I could have a feed of top questions of the day from sites I'm a member of.

The little `StackExchange v` button at the top of each site is lovely, but it often contains questions from sites I'm not really interested in. I'd love something like that for just the sites I'm a member of.

Comment: The question isn't necessarily a dupe, but my answer would be:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70131/stop-the-segregation-madness-merge-all-stack-sites-and-then-differentiate-by-ta/70137#70137

Comment: Yeah.... no. I rather like having the sites separate, that way I only have to sign up for the ones that meet my interests. However it would be nice to be able to browse all my favorites at once.

Comment: Create a Yahoo! Pipe yourself. It isn't that hard :)

Comment: that's exactly the situation my answer on the other question allows for.  Specify the things you want to see.

Answer (score 3):

This may be what you want

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/

at

https://stackexchange.com/tagsets