# Best way to keep track of questions with favourite tags

Tags: support, tag-watching, feed, email-notification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to set up a cross-site feed of Stack Exchange questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70215/is-there-a-way-to-set-up-a-cross-site-feed-of-stack-exchange-questions)

How can I easily see which questions have been asked (and maybe still unanswered) which have my favourite tags?

I am thinking something along the lines of an rss feed or even a daily mail digest.

Is there anything like this out-there, or an option in Stack Overflow sites I have missed?

Comment: You should have such option [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/109684/paulo-j-matos?tab=subscriptions) - create a filter with your desired tags and you can have it sent daily to your email.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are two options.

- Hack into the Stack Exchange API and get the information you want. Read the [manual](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) here.
- Using Stack2rss and get the feeds.

  > http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/questions/unanswered?tagged=php&body=true

  Here I am fetching all the unanswered question in my favourite tag [php](/questions/tagged/php)