# build the tower of Babylon and now you get punished?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

So, all over the world, the leading web technologies (Google, Facebook, etc.) are trying to unite all ways of communication under one umbrella; everyone talks to everybody in the same place (and all provide good filtering mechanisms).

Stack Overflow was the same at the beginning, one place to do them all, with tag filtering (and you can probably add another level, say category filtering).

Instead of that, you started to break everything to smaller and smaller pieces (hope you remember, that was the punishment God gave us for building something too good).

Today, when I ask a web question I get answers like these: "this should have been asked in the Stack Exchange site for web development for developers with the letter E in their name." -- That's a dramatization, but to me it sounds stupid, we did this type of thing 14 years ago, the site is still up and running (it is in Hebrew: http://tapuz.co.il/ ) it has a forum for very specific subjects.

So, while you have good community, it is not more then 10-20 people per forum (I guess that for an English site you should multiply this a by several numbers).  The point is, people are missing data that way.

Another small problem this caused me personally is: I need to ask some questions in Server Fault, which no one wants to answer without a bounty -- acceptable, I just can't accumulate enough points over there, again, the overall effect is loss of knowledge (I do get my answers else where). Why shouldn't points be transferable, at least for this purpose between sites?

The bottom line is: Make your wonderful system as one as possible, do not try to break it to very small pieces any more.

Comment: -1, StackOverflow _never_ was "one place to do them all."

Comment: @radp - not my point, but, never mind. It will happen eventually, just don't know if it will happen soon or late (in which case is usually too late).

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68214/can-stack-exchange-follow-a-more-generic-approach ... maybe.

Comment: Unfortunately, a hypothetical dramatized version of your experience doesn't really help illustrate what is wrong with the current model which SE and SO is operating in. Maybe, you know, a little more facts to back up your claims here will help you?

Comment: @Yi Jiang - No, I wrote what I think, wither you agree or you don't, really does not matter in the long run.

Comment: @Itay if that wasn't your main point then you chose the completely wrong biblical reference.

Comment: We need to pick one "making lots of specialized communities will end the world" post to keep and close the rest as duplicates; this is getting ridiculous

Comment: @radp I believe you miss understood what I meant. Right now it looks to me more like ganging up rather then something I wish to put more energy into and discuss. Take care.

Comment: @Michael Mrozek - how many such post exists, that is interesting.

Comment: *I wrote what I think, wither [sic] you agree or you don't, really does not matter in the long run* -- If what other people think doesn't matter to you, then this isn't a discussion question, it is a rant.

Comment: @Itay I don't want to gang on you right now, but if we're misunderstanding your point then it may have been wiser to skimp on the dramatizations and references and just tell us what you're trying to say. The less directly people state their issues, the less likely we'll ever know what's trying to be said.

Comment: @Grace Note - simple, let ME (the user) decide which topics/categories/sites what ever to see in **one place**. I want to manage it all in one place, not start to "dance around" and guess if there is (and what would be the name) of the specific SO site I am looking for. and if the points would be transferable all over the place, the better.

Comment: By the way, in English it is generally referred to as the "Tower of Babel" (think babelfish).

Answer (score 18):

In college when I wanted to learn about history I went to the building that housed the history department, sat in a room filled with history students, and listened to a history professor. When I wanted to learn about astronomy, I walked over to that building, sat in a different room with different people and listened to a different expert.

I don't think it would have worked well if we all crammed into the football stadium and shouted out "I have a physics question" and waited to see if a physics professor answered.

Each SE site is a different community with different people discussing different subjects using different sets of standards and norms. Further, you know you can count on the quality of the information you're getting because you know the site specializes in that information.

And in case you don't think my college analogy works, just look at Yahoo Answers.

Comment: Yahoo! Answers is a football stadium filled with 12 year olds shouting anatomy questions.  Great analogy.  :)

Comment: :-) and I sent mail via the post office

Comment: @Itay - point being?

Comment: Why all the hate towards yahoo answers? It's a very successful website that simply targets a different demographic; most of us wouldn't fit very well in there, but many people there wouldn't fit here. To each their own, no need to keep making fun of it.

Comment: @Kop - it makes fun of itself.

Comment: this is a great post, referring this to Joel and Robert and Rebecca as well

Answer (score 13):

This has been brought up several times before.  If we combine all the communities into one, what we will end up with is Yahoo! Answers.  Building a community that's focused one thing is what made Stack Overflow work so well.

Comment: Focus! Focus! Focus! Not that the focus needs to be *too* tight. The focus that drove Stack Overflow from the beginning was "Programming", which is a pretty big tent all by itself.

Comment: No, if you replace the moderation system with something completely broken you'll end up with yahoo answers.

Answer (score 5):

I think [this talk](http://www.webstock.org.nz/talks/speakers/jeff-atwood/stack-overflow-building-social-software-anti-socia/) can help you understand what's going on here. The title, however, should say it all:

> ### Stack Overflow: Building Social Software for the Anti-Social

Should the video not load, [here's a direct link](http://2009.r2.co.nz/20100218/jeff-a.mp4). Here, have [the slides](http://www.slideshare.net/codinghorror/webstock-2010-stack-overflow-building-social-software-for-the-antisocial) too.

But the short of it is: Stack Overflow isn't what you think it is. It's no place to socialize. It's no place for general chit chat. It's a place for people to get programming answers, in the most pragmatic way possible.

---

Transferring reputation is a good idea, and indeed [you get 100 free reps every time you link your account to another account on a different site that has at least 200 rep.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites)

If you think that's not enough, you'll have to further explain your case.

---

Your traffic points aren't substantiated by *facts*, so I won't address them. Here, [have some facts.](https://stackexchange.com/sites) How many users are there on *your* forum?

Comment: that facts page I can't use to prove or dis-prove unless we know how many users are shared between the sites. I am not even aware most of them exists... I gave the statistics of that forum in the post itself.

Answer (score 2):

You may not be fully aware of how the [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) mechanism works. It is a multiple stage process that requires a increasing number of participants to build a community from the germ of an idea; into a well specified idea; into the kernel of a site with a core group of committed users; into a working beta site; into a full fledged, independent member of the League of Justice (are we still using that metaphor?).

This limits the degree of fragmentation that will be possible, and indeed has already caused some proposed sites to be merged or dropped altogether.

Add to the the [StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/66838#66838) and the sidebar highlighting of the Stack Exchange "hottest" questions and the easy cross-site sign up (with rep bonus to get over the no-privileges hump), and despite having many sites, you really do have one community.

Answer (score 1):

Since you gave a hypothetical, dramatical version of the future, let me see what it would actually look like:

[image]

Is there the slightest, remotest possibility that this will happen? **No.**

Case closed.

Comment: Lol, so I'm Erica now ;-).

Comment: @Gamecat - Sorry, ran out of names starting with the letter 'E'

Comment: How did Raj get an account on that site?!