# Stack Exchange home page tailored to logged in users

Tags: feature-request, users, stackexchange.com

Could the [Stack Exchange home page](https://stackexchange.com/) be more tailored to each user when logged in? Maybe have a large visually appealing status of activity on their selected communities, etc. Maybe this could even be customizable?

Probably not top priority, but would be nice to have at some point.

---

**Update:**

Pops is on to something [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68228/228367) (I know it's an old post):
[image: Pops SE mockup]

Comment: You can bookmark your profile page. Wouldn't that do?

Comment: I think I get what you're suggesting but a mockup would help motivate this proposal

Comment: I would start by having the total network reputation and badges in the top bar. @Oded is this feasible at all? (heavily cached of course :))

Comment: @Oded Not quite what I'm thinking. Richard is right that I need a good mockup of what I'm proposing. I'll see if I can draft one up later.

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind is having your stats show in the sites slider in the homepage.

Comment: By "activity", do you mean "hot and new interesting questions on the sites you participate"?  Sort of like the SO default page but across the network.

Comment: Something like the app feeds could be nice...

Comment: @Troyen Yes! That's one of the central things that I would like to see.